# Usage about pronoun who

Tags: pronouns

I was writing something like: *Speaking is an umbrella term itself who encompasses grammar, vocabulary, fluency and accuracy and pronunciation.*

Herein lies two problem, 1.can i use who here?
2.does this sentence make sense? i'm not  sure if i used umbrella term properly here

Please help me and do not be so pedantic, thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing to add to the answers given is the "which that" choice.  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/

Answer (score 5):

No you can't.

**Who** is used for people and sometimes for other creatures that are anthropomorphised (or given human personalities in folk tales and sometimes in personal relationships with animals).

You need to use the relative pronoun **which** or **that**.

Otherwise, the sentence is fine, except that you require a **comma** rather than **and** after **fluency**.

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-which/

Answer (score 4):

Speaking is an umbrella term itself (**which encompasses**) / (**encompassing**) grammar, vocabulary, fluency, accuracy and pronunciation.